# cmake - put output of private library into directory under top level of source instead of under build

Tags: cmake

I have a (temporarily) odd source tree where private libraries are built and used by executables elsewhere in the source tree, but they are not tied together by cmake (yet).  The executables being built need to be able to locate these libs during compile time and I'd prefer to not have to reference them under path/to/src/build/lib or whatever.

And unfortunately, I cannot change how these two, nearly separate parts are referenced at the top.

Basic Structure:

```
topLevel
  |- privLibs
  |----CMakeLists.txt (currently only does add_subdirectory(libX)
  |----lib (outputdir from make install)
  |----include (public header output dir from make install)
  |----libA
  |-------CMakeLists.txt  
  |----libB
  |-------CMakeLists.txt
  |_ ExeA 
  |----CMakeLists.txt (Depends on libA and libB)
  |_ ExeB
  |----CMakeLists.txt (Depends on Lib A)
```

So is there a rational way to have privLibs put libA.so and libB.so into:  privLibs/libs during compile?  Or do I have to force the issue by running a make install in privLibs first? Or, is this just something that is not done.  I know I can do a find_library call with hints to privLibs/build/lib, but that seems undesirable.

topLevel libs CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(liby VERSION 0.0.1 DESCRIPTION "liby library group")

add_subdirectory(libA)
add_subdirectory(libB)
```

libA CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(libA VERSION 0.0.1 DESCRIPTION "libA library")

include (FindPkgConfig)
include (GNUInstallDirs)


set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

set(PKG_CONFIG_USE_CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH True)

#Perform Package Checks for standard system libraries.
find_library(SOMELIB NAMES somelib HINTS /path/to/lib NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
 
include_directories(../include)


#List and add Sources to compile
set (SOURCES
    libcode.c
)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${SOURCES})
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES VERSION 0.0.0 SOVERSION 0 PUBLIC_HEADER "libcode.h")

install (TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} DESTINATION lib PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION include )


##link needed libraries
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
  ${SOMELIB}
)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC 
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}
)
```

Just not sure what the best way to get ExeA to reference privLibs/lib/libX.so.

Comment: would copying the files do, or does it have to be the compiler output directly to the root folder?

Comment: Copying the file might be fine.  Not sure if there's any downsides to that, besides an extra line in the cmake file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set_target_properties(libA PROPERTIES
LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs)

Accomplishes what I needed during compile time.  make install still works to put them in the proper final location for full install.

UPDATE:  while this works, trying to use ADDITIONAL_CLEAN_FILES to clean the libs directory causes a rebuild not to re-copy the lib to ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs, thus causing other things dependent on libA to fail to link.

added a set_property(DIRETORY PROPERTY ADDITIONAL_CLEAN_FILES "{CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs") and moved the LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY to the top level CMakeLists.txt as:
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs") to accomplish what I needed.